# Discrete Math quantifiers,proof and demonstrating with symbols

Tags: first-order-logic

In my Discrete Math course, I encounter a question such as
$$\exists x\forall y\,x<y \text{ where }x,y\in\mathbb{Z}\,,$$
and I explain it like this: "Let $x=1$ and $y=-2$ For an $x$ in the universe not all $y$ values make the statement $x < y$ true so the case is $1$ is not equal $-2$" and I think this is sufficient for explaining but I wonder whether there is a way to indicate proof with symbols or mathematically. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did "is not equal to" come from? Nothing in the formula says "is not equal to", except insofar as if $x<y$ then they're not equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With quantifiers, you can't choose the specific values in all cases. In particular:

- You can choose a specific value for an $\exists$-quantified variable to prove a statement true, but not to prove it false.
- You can choose a specific value for a $\forall$-quantified variable to prove a statement false, but not to prove it true.

What you've done is proved that there is a particular $x$ that the statement doesn't hold for. But that doesn't mean that there isn't another value that it does hold for! (Or at least, it doesn't inherently mean that). If you're showing there doesn't exist an $x$, you need to show that the statement $\forall y \ldotp x < y$ is false for *every* single $x$, not just a specific $x$.

Comment: Could you widen a bit?How can I proof that equation?

Comment: @merekes Are you trying to prove it false or true? In any case, I'm not going to do your homework for you. To prove it true, you need to find a value of $x$, and for arbitrary $y$ (i.e. making no assumptions about the value of $y$, other than that it is in $\mathbb{Z}$), show that $x < y$. To prove it false, you need to leave $x$ arbitrary (other than it being in $\mathbb{Z}$, and pick a specific value of $y$ where $x < y$ is false.